# The term $rank$ in methematics

Tags: soft-question, terminology, definition, big-list

Reading [wikipedia's disambiguation page about the "rank"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%5f%28disambiguation%29) word I see many concept of rank of many different matematical object.

I only know about the rank of a graded poset and the rank of a set that tell us its position in the Von Neumann hierarcy. In these two cases the "rank" concept give us *a value of one element in relation to the other elements* or ***help us to order them in hierarchies or classify them in some way.***

Is this always true? There is a general definition/concept of rank in mathematics? What have in common all these rank concepts and what are the differences?

Comment: The word "rank" refers indeed to several related concepts in mathematics, and if you only know about the rank of a graded poset and set rank, then matrix rank, group rank, quadratic form rank, tensor rank etc. might be very interesting for you (it would help to see the differences and similarities, too).

Comment: And yes, it denotes the position in some kind of order or hierarchy, like military rank. See also http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=rank&allowed_in_frame=0